# JAWS is not reading the select options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jaws-screen-reader

I am doing a project on JAWS, I have return a html code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page title</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <script src="<%out.print(request.getContextPath());%>/jquery/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script> 

        <script src="<%out.print(request.getContextPath());%>/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="<%out.print(request.getContextPath());%>/jquery/jquery-ui.css"></link>

        <link href="<%out.print(request.getContextPath());%>/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css?v=2" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="<%out.print(request.getContextPath());%>/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js?v=2"></script>

        <script src="<%out.print(request.getContextPath());%>/select2/maximize-select2-height/maximize-select2-height.js"></script>
        <script src="<%out.print(request.getContextPath());%>/select2/maximize-select2-height/maximize-select2-height.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="<%out.print(request.getContextPath());%>/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.form-control').select2({
                    theme: "classic",
                    templateSelection: function (data, container) {
                        if (data.id == '') {
                            $(container).css("color", "grey");
                        } else {
                            $(container).css("color", "black");
                        }
                        return data.text;
                    },
                }).maximizeSelect2Height();
               
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div>
            <div class ="col-sm-3">
                <label for="app1">Name:</label>
            </div>
            <div class ="col-sm-9">                        
                <select required class = "form-control" id ="app1">
                    <option value="" >select a program name</option>
                    <option >india</option>
                    <option >china</option>
                    <option>netherlands</option>
                    <option >africa</option>
                    <option >nepal</option>
                    <option >india</option>
                    <option >china</option>
                    <option>netherlands</option>
                    <option >africa</option>
                    <option >nepal</option>
                    <option >india</option>
                    <option >china</option>
                    <option>netherlands</option>
                    <option >africa</option>
                    <option >nepal</option>
                    
                </select>             
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

The output will be like: [image]

when I run the JAWS its reading everything out of the drpdown box but it is not reading the options to select. I need the text search in the dropdown its a requirement. If I remove the text search which I have used select2 plugin for that its working fine but I need that search box is there any other alternative plugin which I can use.

Comment: what browser???

Comment: I am using chrome

Comment: higher importance is IE both gives me same output

Comment: It says select the program name combo box to change the selection use arrow keys, I will be hitting enter then it says enter edit type in text and when I use down arrow it wont speak or read.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code in your question is just a simple <select> but your screenshot looks like you want to have an <input> that automatically displays the dropdown to allow for selection.  Those two user experiences are quite different.  To do the latter, follow the [Combo Box pattern](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#combobox) on "WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices 1.1".

I think the problem you are having is that the <input> has focus so the down arrow is being sent to the <input> since JAWS typically switches to "forms mode" when focus moves to an input.  In "forms mode", you can't use the screen reader's normal keyboard shortcuts to navigate the page.

You'll probably need a keyboard handler to capture the down arrow key and use [`aria-activedescendant`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-activedescendant) to tell the screen reader where the "focus" should be.

See also "[5.6.2 Managing Focus in Composites Using aria-activedescendant](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#kbd_focus_activedescendant)".

Comment: the input box which I have got is a placeholder by select2 plugin which I ahve been using in the jQUery. I see there is also selectWoo plugin which can be used and also works I am unable to get the placeholder when I use it directly